# Google+ api OAuth 2.0 : how to access token object 'authResult' from .js file

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

I have a HTML/CSS/JS app using Jquery Mobile, in which I would like to create a sign-up page.

The function `signinCallback` in the .html perfectly finds the variable called `authResult` (OAuth 2.0 Token Object), but **in the .js `authResult` is undefined** and therefore the function `signinCallback` doesn't work (see info on this function here : https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/disconnect) nor other api's methods like `gapi.auth.getToken();`.

I get the following **errors** from the .js file :

`ReferenceError: gapi is not defined`

`ReferenceError: authResult is not defined`
Can you help me figure out why ?

Thanks.

The .html:

```
    <!-- SIGN-IN PAGE -->
<div id="signin-page" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">
    <header data-role="header">
    </header>
    <div id="contentsignin" data-role="content">                
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function signinCallback(authResult) {
            console.log(' --signinCallback in script in .html');
                  if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
                  } else {
                  }
                }
    </script>
    <span id="signinButton">
          <span
            class="g-signin"
            data-callback="signinCallback"
            data-clientid="myclientid"
            data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
            data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
            data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
          </span>
        </span>
        <button type="button" id="revokeButton">
            Revoke token...
        </button>
        </div>
 </div>


...

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        })();
    </script>
```

The .js:

```
    var testtest = gapi.auth.getToken();
    $('#revokeButton').click(disconnectUser);

console.log(authResult);

function disconnectUser(authResult) {
    var access_token = authResult['access_token'];
      var revokeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' +
         access_token;
      // Perform an asynchronous GET request.
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: revokeUrl,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(nullResponse) {
         // Do something now that user is disconnected
         // The response is always undefined.
         document.getElementById('loginstatusin').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
         document.getElementById('loginstatusin').setAttribute('style', 'display: block');
        },
        error: function(e) {
         // Handle the error
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: The error "ReferenceError: gapi is not defined" may come from the fact that your script code executes before the Google library is loaded and thus gapi is still undefined. It may be because it's late but it seems to me that the sample from the Google site cannot work :?

Comment: Thanks @Ivancho. I placed it just before the `<\body>` tag because they explicitly mention to put it here https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button-javascript#step_2_include_the_google_script_on_your_page. What's wrong with how they load the library...can you help me figure it out?

Comment: I clarified my question : the variable `authResult` is accessible from the .html file, but not from the .js file....that's my problem in fact.

Comment: Anyone ?   By the way it seems that the loading of the Google lib is asynchronous, so it shouldn't matter where if is after or before.

Comment: anyone can answer this ? is the question weird or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Its a little bit late answer but I think you need to first download js script which contains `authResult` and then download your own .js file so that when code in your .js file is executing, `authResult` related code is already downloaded and present for  your code.

```
<script src="path\to\js_file\containing\authResult"></script>
<script src="path\to\your\js_file.js"></script>
```